# how to change Morris bar color base on series key value?

Tags: bar-chart, morris.js

I'm trying to set a custom color for the bar chart in morris.js. But in my code it only change the hover label text only.

Here is my code:

```
    var chart = Morris.Bar({
        element : 'morris-bar-chart',
        data : [ {y : '2006-05-01', user : 1, beed : 90 }, 
                 {y : '2006-05-01', user : 2, beed : 80 }, 
                 {y : '2006-05-01', user : 3, beed : 70 }, 
                 {y : '2006-05-02', user : 1, beed : 190}, 
                 {y : '2006-05-02', user : 1, beed : 290}, 
                 {y : '2006-05-01', user : 2, beed : 90 }, 
                 {y : '2006-05-02', user : 3,beed : 90  } ],
        barColors : function(row, series, type) {
        console.log("--> "+row.label, series, type); // output in console
            if (series.key == 'user' || series.key == 'beed') { // Doesn't work if series.key == 'beed' not included in if condition. 
                if (row.y == '1')
                    return "#1AB244"; // green
                else
                    return "#fec04c"; // orange
            }
        },
        xkey : 'y',
        ykeys : [ 'user', 'beed' ],
        labels : [ 'User: ', 'Beed: ' ],
        xLabelAngle : 45,
        hideHover : 'auto',
        resize : true,
        stacked : true
    });
```

I know its much easier to change the bar char color by changing **xkey** to value to **'user'** then used the code below:

```
barColors: function (row, series, type) {
if(row.label == "1") return "#1AB244"; // green
else return "#fec04c"; // orange
}
```

But I want to change the color of whole bar chart color where **'y'** is the xkey where all user equal to **'1'** set to **green** color then the rest of bar chart is set to **orange** color. Is this possible to achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is easier to define the colors array first using javascript by checking your dataset, and then apply it through the setting *barColors*.